# Key hash doesn't match in Android Facebook log in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am getting an error when trying to log in to Facebook on my app:

Invalid key hash. The key hash ("a key hash displayed here") does not match any stored key hashed. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/...

I have looked online and people say that I should copy the hash that it is displaying into my app dashboard. However, I can't copy it on my Android phone, and I can't write it out because it has several l's and I's (which both look exactly the same). So what should I do here?

Comment: just print it in the log

Comment: When you run your project in different PC it is change automatically.